# Inject mouse events handling on elements below an overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation where I would like to handle event of mouse over of the element which is below the overlay.

pointer-events do work but my problem is that i do not have access to that code. I would like to inject the code to a website where i do not have any access.

Take for example below:

```js
document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{alert('mouse event');});
```

```html
<div id="topDiv" style="width:100px;height:50px;">
<img id="img" mouseover="javascript:alert('mouse moved over image);" src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2016/07/08/117156_media_512x512.png"style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
<!-- Commenting or hiding the overlay div below would trigger the event otherwise not -->
<div id="divOverlay" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @mplungjan Just updated the question. Please check again.

Comment: @mplungjan i think i forgot to add a limitation to my question. pointer-events do work but my problem is that i do not have access to that code. I would like to inject the code to a website where i do not have any access. I already searched the google for the possible solution couldn't find any. One way is to find all the elements below the pointer co-ordinates but i was looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: That is pertinent information. Why did we have to wait three iterations of this question to understand your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might try `document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)` method to get an elements list indicating the elements under your cursor.

```
document.querySelector('#divOverlay').addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  console.log(document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));
});
```

Now when the mouse is over the `img` element beneath the overlay, you will get an elements list like `[div#divOverlay, img#img, ...]`. By this way you indirectly get to know when the cursor is over the `img`.

However, as this is in a `mousemove` event handler, you may need to add some extra logic like removing the event listener after the first time you detect your `img` being under the cursor - if you actually only need a `mouseover` action on it.